# Internal Servlet mapping - web.xml

Tags: java, web-services, jsp, servlets

I wanted to know if there is any way of creating a servlet-mapping which can be only accessed within the webapplication. For example a file inside this application calls another file but it sould not be accessable from outside the web-app.

Thank You,

Comment: Where have you placed your web files? If you place them in web-inf folder, it will not be accessible to outside world.

Comment: what ever the mapping you have done in web.xml is global, so I don't think you can restrict like you have asked. One way may be write a Filter which checks for request headers (or) certain parameter to differentiate browser call (or) internal call then decide whether to forward to servlet (or)  return to error page.

Comment: Thanks for the filter advise. I have implemented that and works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes there is a way. Placing your restricted jsp files inside your web-inf directory. Then importing those jsp's in other jsp's is perfectly legal and wont cause you any problem.

see an example jsp below:

```
<%@page import="admin.*"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-tiles.tld" prefix="tiles" %>
<tiles:insert template='myTemplate.jsp'>
  <tiles:put name='top' content='/WEB-INF/templates/top.jsp''/>  
  <tiles:put name='main' content='/WEB-INF/templates/main.jsp''/>  
  <tiles:put name='footer' content='/WEB-INF/templates/footer.jsp'/>
</tiles:insert>
```